# ASP.NET, AJAX - 403 forbidden

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I'm getting the error

```
**POST http://localhost:34169/createNew.aspx.cs/Confirm 403 (Forbidden) **
```

when I am trying to call a CodeBehind function with Jquery AJAX.

My code:

```
function CallConfirmMethod(str) {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "createNew.aspx.cs/Confirm",
                data: "{'smallPos': " + str + "}",
                success: function (result) { alert("successful!"); }
            });
        }
```

And the CodeBehind function (doesnt actually do anything, just to test things out):

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(BufferResponse = false)]
        protected void Confirm(string str) {
            // SKICKA SQL-QUERY
            Response.Write("Funktionen kallas! " + str);
        }
```

Comment: What you are using? IIS or ASP.NET Development Server?

Comment: Have you tried GET instead of POST ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your mistake is in url createNew.aspx.cs/Confirm you should change it to **createNew.aspx/Confirm**. Also it's good article [Calling ASP.Net WebMethod using jQuery AJAX](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)

Comment: You are right @kolesso. The server is forbidding the response because it has been requested against the code-behind file, which is not served (Forbidden) by the server.

Comment: Changing the URL to createNew.aspx/Confirm gives me error 500 instead (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) ), which I guess is a step in the right direction atleast. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Now the problem is with passing the parameter to `Confirm` method, I think.

Comment: Maybe change this data: "{'smallPos': " + str + "}", to data: {"str": str}.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you get 500, because you haven't close Response

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(BufferResponse = false)]
protected void Confirm(string str) {
  // SKICKA SQL-QUERY
  Response.Clear();
  Response.ContentType = "application/text";
  Response.StatusCode = 200;
  Response.Write("Funktionen kallas! " + str);
  Response.Flush();
  Response.End();   
}
```

if you want send response in json this is article [AJAX to web method not returning JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423406/ajax-to-web-method-not-returning-json)